# Method to strip HTML tags not in a safe list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a method that strips all HTML tags that are not on a safe tags list? If there isn't, what would be <strike>a regex</strike> the method to achieve it?

<strike>I'm looking for something just like PHP's [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.</strike>

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What the hell is that question? How can it possible have anything to do with my question? Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NullUserException answer is perfect, I made a little extension method to do it and I'm posting here if anyone else needs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace Extenders
{
    public static class StringExtender
    {
        internal static void ParseHtmlDocument(XmlDocument doc, XmlNode root, string[] allowedTags, string[] allowedAttributes, string[] allowedStyleKeys)
        {
            XmlNodeList nodes;

            if (root == null) root = doc.ChildNodes[0];
            nodes = root.ChildNodes;

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (!(allowedTags.Any(x => x.ToLower() == node.Name.ToLower())))
                {
                    var safeNode = doc.CreateTextNode(node.InnerText);
                    root.ReplaceChild(safeNode, node);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (node.Attributes != null)
                    {
                        var attrList = node.Attributes.OfType<XmlAttribute>().ToList();
                        foreach (XmlAttribute attr in attrList)
                        {
                            if (!(allowedAttributes.Any(x => x.ToLower() == attr.Name)))
                            {
                                node.Attributes.Remove(attr);
                            }
                            // TODO: if style is allowed, check the allowed keys: values
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                    ParseHtmlDocument(doc, node, allowedTags, allowedAttributes, allowedStyleKeys);
            }
        }

        public static string ParseSafeHtml(this string input, string[] allowedTags, string[] allowedAttributes, string[] allowedStyleKeys)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<span>" + input + "</span>");

            ParseHtmlDocument(xmlDoc, null, allowedTags, allowedAttributes, allowedStyleKeys);

            string result;

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
                    xmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);

                result = sw.ToString();
            }

            return result.Substring(6, result.Length - 7);
        }
    }
}
```

To use:

```
var x = "<b>allowed</b><b class='text'>allowed attr</b><b id='5'>not allowed attr</b><i>not all<b>o</b>wed tag</i>".ParseSafeHtml((new string[] { "b", "#text" }), (new string[] { "class" }), (new string[] { }));
```

Which outputs:

```
<b>allowed</b><b class='text'>allowed attr</b><b>not allowed attr</b>not allowed tag
```

If the element is not allowed it will get the innerText and pull out the tag, removing all inner tags.

Comment: +1! but one question..why `<ul></ul>` or `<li></li>` is ignored (not removed/checked)?

Answer (score 7):

[Do. Not. Use. Regex. To. Parse. HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use an XML parser:
[MSDN Reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.xml.xmldocument.aspx&ei=IaBhTL3GF8iUOJPKwLUK&usg=AFQjCNE8WC46At536fmBLTtmkEDW6ZJTQw&sig2=7JwzXc7unncubmjm4BM8zA)
[Simple Tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=opera&hs=QyZ&rls=en&q=xml+parser+C%23&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
[HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I love that post. I never get tired of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MS AntiXSS library to sanitize potentially-executable HTML. Take a look at it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx

http://wpl.codeplex.com/