# How safe is it to accept a pre-defined set of non-harmful HTML tags from a request?

Tags: html, tags, tinymce, security

One of the first things I learned as a web developer was to never ever accept any HTML from the client. (Perhaps only if I HTML encode it.)
I use a WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) that outputs HTML. So far I have only used it on an admin page, but now I'd like to also use it on a forum. It has a BBCode module, but that seems to be incomplete. (It is possible that BBCode itself doesn't support everything I want it to.)

So, here's my idea:

I allow the client to directly POST some HTML code. Then, I check the code for sanity (**well-formedness**) and remove all tags, attributes, and CSS rules that are not allowed based on a pre-defined set of allowed tags and styles.
Obviously I would allow the stuff that can be outputted by the subset of TinyMCE functionality I use.

I would allow the following tags:
`span`, `sub`, `sup`, `a`, `p`, `ul`, `ol`, `li`, `img`, `strong`, `em`, `br`

With the following attributes:
`style` (for everything), `href` and `title` (for `a`), `alt` and `src` (for `img`)

And the following CSS rules:
`color`, `font`, `font-size`, `font-weight`, `font-style`, `text-decoration`

These cover everything that I need for formatting, and (as far as I know) don't present any security risk. Basically, the enforcement of well-formedness and the lack of any layouting styles prevent anyone to hurt the layout of the site. The disallow of the script tag and the likes prevent XSS.
(One exception: maybe I should allow `width`/`height` in a predefined range for images.)

**Other advantage:** this stuff would save me from the need to write / look for a BBCode-Html converter.

What do you think?
Is this a secure thing to do?

(As I see, StackOverflow also allows some basic HTML in the "About Me" field, so I think I'm not the first one to implement this.)

**EDIT:**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452322/method-to-strip-html-tags-not-in-a-safe-list) which explains how to do this fairly easily.
And of course, [noone should think about using regex for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

The question itself is not related to any language or technology, but if you are wondering, I write this application in ASP.NET.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I was actually thinking about doing something like this for myself. I'll watch this question to see what people say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unclear what programming language you're using or are preferring, but in Java there's [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), which is a pretty slick HTML parser API which contains among others a HTML cleaner based on a customizable whitelist of HTML tags and attributes (unfortunately no CSS rules since that's completely out the scope of a HTML parser). Here's an extract of relevance from [its site](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

> ### [Sanitize untrusted HTML](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)
>
> #### Problem
>
> You want to allow untrusted users to supply HTML for output on your website (e.g. as comment submission). You need to clean this HTML to avoid [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attacks.
>
> #### Solution
>
> Use the jsoup HTML [`Cleaner`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html) with a configuration specified by a [`Whitelist`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html).
>
> ```
> String unsafe = 
>       "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
> String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
>       // now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
> ```

The [`Whitelist`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) class itself contains several predefinied whitelists which may be of use, like [`Whitelist#basic()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#basic%28%29) and [`Whitelist#relaxed()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#relaxed%28%29).

For .NET, there's by the way a Jsoup port with the name [NSoup](http://nsoup.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This NSoup thingy has made it very simple! Thanks for the link! :)

Comment: Interesting fact: this port was triggered by [one of my Jsoup answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program/2835555#2835555) :) (check the comments)

Comment: very nice :) The only thing I miss from it is the cleanup of CSS rules. (Or is it there? I couldn't found it.)

Comment: NSoup basically solved the problem for me, so I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP, check out [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), it filters out with very advanced customizable settings (like allowed/disallowed tags, attributes, styles, etc), including XSS and tricky style (e.g. `display: none`) protection.

Also, TinyMCE does do a bit of filtering but since it's client-side you're not supposed to trust it anyway.

Comment: Well, the first-ever rule of web development is, never ever rely on client-side-only validation. :) Thanks for the PHP link, though I don't use PHP, I have a few friends who do. I can recommend it to them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Of the tags you plan to allow, `<a>` definitely requires extra attention, due to the possibility of `javascript:` URLs. And of course you need to disallow javascript event handlers from all tags.

Comment: of course you are right. Your answer made me undestrand what the `AddProtocols` method in NSoup is for. Thanks! :)

Comment: if by the javascript event handlers you mean the `onload`, `onclick` etc., those will be erased since they are not among the allowed attributes. Is there anything else that needs to be taken care of against javascript?

Comment: Also watch out for Opera, as it allows for `javascript:` in img tags' `src` attributes...