# How do I prevent the user from entering '>' and '<' characters with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to prevent user from entering '>' and '<' character. How should i do this? I tried to implement this by ( via javascript) detecting their keycodes but since '>' and '.' have the same keycode, it also prevented '.' from being entered. The same happens for the ',' and '<' characters. How should i do this?

Below is what i have tried.

```
    $('#Notes').bind('keydown', function() {
        if (window.event) {

            if ((window.event.keyCode == 190) || (window.event.keyCode == 188)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: could you please provide the code what you tired

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the input on the server side. This is a necessity. Data from the client side cannot be trusted at all. Imagine what will happen if someone disables your script in their browser. I recommend you to simply replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`, or remove them alltogether. (Alternatively, you could also strip the input from any HTML tags.) This is a safe and simple solution.

Even better than that, you could allow **some** HTML tags to be posted (basic text formatting, for example), and use an HTML sanitizer to remove disallowed content from it.
I have had much success with NSoup for this purpose.
About the latter, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740366/how-safe-is-it-to-accept-a-pre-defined-set-of-non-harmful-html-tags-from-a-reques).

Answer (score 4):

Monitoring the keystrokes themselves is much more complicated then simply validating the input field. Maybe try something like this in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myTextArea").onkeyup = function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/<|>/g, "");
}
```

Comment: @LeguRi Yeah, that should probably be onchange instead of onkeyup. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

If this is to prevent x-site scripting then you should let the controller take care of it.  Or maybe you could do the replace inside the controller code.

I also use `Server.HtmlDecode(model.value);` in the view.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("owner", Server.HtmlDecode(Model.owner), new { @class = "ForumItemTitleEntry", name = "title" })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the input on the server side. There is no other solution.

But as an answer for your question, give [this](http://jsbin.com/adise3/edit) little code snippet a try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Notes").bind("keydown", function(ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode === 226)
      ev.preventDefault();
  })
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to prevent from entering in textbox?

If that is the case then you can do the following.

```
jQuery("#textid").keyUp(function(){

    if (jQuery('#textid').val().indexOf('<') != -1) {
                    jQuery('#textid').val(jQuery('#textid').val().replace('<', ''));
                }
    else if(jQuery('#textid').val().indexOf('>') != -1) {
                    jQuery('#textid').val(jQuery('#textid').val().replace('>', ''));
                }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify char-keys, always observe onkeypress instead of other key-events, keypress will give you the correct keycode.
I recommend the use of firebug, it would have give you a notice about this.

But like the many others said, you also must validate this on the serverside, while there are many other ways to insert chars into a textbox.
What you like to do could only be a feature for the convenience of your users, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I used [jquery and numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) to restrict user input to decimal numbers. Admittedly not quite what your looking for, but still worth a shout I thought.